# Chartjs listening mouseup breaks legend click

Tags: chart.js

I have a custom plugin for Chart.js that has to listen to the mouseup event. When I wanted to add a feature of disabling a signal by clicking the legend, legend clicking wasn't working, neither the default or the custom onClick. Using custom onClick I found out that the click is run twice for each click, first one disabling and second one enabling the signal again immediately. If I remove mouseup from events, legend click is only run once. It is not possible to pass events list to legend and stop it listening mouseup.

I was able to circumvent the issue by returning false in the custom plugin event handler.

```
{
      id: 'customPlugin',
      beforeEvent(chart, args) {
        if (args.event.type === 'mouseup') {
          console.log('mouse up');
          this.isDragging = false;
          return false; // if doesnt return false, legend click is run twice
        }
      },
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-xkhcjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

But I'm wondering, can this really be the intended usage. What if I have another plugin also listening to mouseup?

Answer (score 1):

All plugins can be configured with `events` option as array of events types to catch.

For your use case, I think it could be:

```
options: {
   // mouseup must be add to chart
   events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove', 'mouseup'],
   plugins: {
     legend: {
       events: ['mouseup'] // only mouseup is caught and managed by legend as click
     }
   }      
}
```

If you want to catch only click to legend (and ignore mouseup):

```
options: {
   // mouseup must be add to chart
   events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove', 'mouseup'],
   plugins: {
     legend: {
       events: ['click'] // only click is caught and managed by legend as click
     }
   }      
}
```

Comment: That is how plugins usually work, but that is not the case for Legend. You can try by uncommenting the events property in the code example. I'm using version 4.3.0. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Comment: It's not correct as far as I know seeing the code of Chart.js, All plugins (legend included) can be configured by events option and they will receive the events by before/afterEVent hooks. Codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/wvYXzRe

Comment: It looks like events is missing from typings then.

Comment: No, it's there [index.d.ts](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/types/index.d.ts#L1641), was the first thing I checked

Comment: @kikon from legend options... https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/types/index.d.ts#L2318

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your previous message, I thought you meant about the `events` slot that it's not in typings;  but there's no `events` in the *legend options* (in your code and our derivations of it),  but in the *chart options* (and the plugin, but that's not creating problems). Anyway, that's not important.

Comment: In my code, if I add events property to legend plugin, it shows an error, because chartjs legend plugin does not have events property in it's typings (.d.ts file). That is the reason I'm not able to use events property in my code, because typescript doesn't compile with an error. Typescript is strongly typed which javascript is not, which is the reason pure javascript compiles and typescript does not.

Answer (score 0):

@user2057925 is right, and one should configure the `events` property as he says. In particular, without some of those events one will lose the tooltip. Indeed, I think you found a bug. Just in terms of a short explanation, there are two different problems exposed by your code

#### Problem 1 (strange behavior)

If `options.plugins.legend.onClick` is defined,
then the default 'click' behavior is not triggered (this
is reasonable), nor is there a documented way to do so (not so reasonable).

The solution is to search for the original `onClick` method
in the `Chart` object, using the source code:

```js
onClick: (...args) => {
    console.log('legend click');
    
    // if using modules, import Legend with Chart
    // import {Chart, registrables, Legend} from './chart.js'
    Legend.defaults.onClick(...args);
    // // if using standard script tag with the chartjs umd just:
    // Chart.Legend.defaults.onClick(...args);
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpc1w5gk/)

#### Problem 2 (bug)

If the chart's `options.events` contains both `mouseup` and `click`, then the click event is trigger twice, anywhere on
the chart, irrespective to the existence of plugins (one may comment the whole plugin section on OP's code).

This is apparent for the legend for which the default behavior
is that the second click cancels the
effect of the first (hides and then shows the clicked
dataset) [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbvgx69y/).

This is a bug, also in my opinion.

It is due to the function
[`_isClickEvent(e)`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v4.3.0/src/helpers/helpers.core.ts#L414)
that returns `true` if `e.type === 'mouseup'`. The function is
called in the method
[`Chart#_handleEvent`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v4.3.0/src/core/core.controller.js#L1232),
and although this is the only place it is called in the
chart.js main code, it is possible there are good reasons
for this behavior; but then the `_handleEvent` should take
into account that the user declared both event types in
`options.events`.

This behavior is not related to the plugins, however, the OP
found already **the best solution**: if the plugin handler returns `false` the situation is saved; this *is* the documented behavior, see
`Plugin#`[`beforeEvent`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/api/interfaces/Plugin.html#beforeevent):

> If any plugin returns false, the event will be discarded.

although it does seem somewhat arbitrary -- a plugin cancelling
an event globally might impact another plugin, messing
with a much-needed separation in design (a plugin implementer
can't possibly know what other plugins are added
by a user).

I would not recommend the other obvious solution, to just exclude `click` from the `options.events` when one has already `mouseup` (since click will be triggered by mouseup anyway) -- it's difficult to take into consideration all possible interactions with all the components of the library.